# I have two images, If I ,,hover" over the second, the first must change on this second image

Tags: image, hover

first  src=>img/header.jpg alt=>first />

second src=>img/pexels-photo-261146.jpeg alt=>second />

## second:hover - first `background-image:url(img/pexels-photo-261146.jpeg);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to be more clear on what you're asking because I'm not quite understanding, but wat I can deduce is that you want to change the first image when you hover the second one. What you should try to do is something like

```
<image1 id="change">
<image2 onmouseover="changeFirst(change);">

function changeFirst(String id){
    $("#id").attr("src", "secondImage.jpg");
}
```

Like this your function in Jquery recieves the id of the tag that you want to change the src attribute and the you can change the image.